# Knockout, why do we need the parameter for notifySubscribers?

Tags: knockout.js

Sometimes we need to use notifySubscribers to enforce the execution of subscirbers of an observable, you can pass a param to notifySubscribers, but the problem is the passed param neither changes the value of the the observable, nor does it getting passed to the subsriber, then why is it used? I saw in some Knockout doc, a param is passed, for example, in [this one](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html). Here is a [jsfiddle code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/amoicity/t3sdo503/), which validates the fact the param is not used anywhere. Am I missing something, or is the param indeed meaningless?

Code in jsfiddle
html

```
<div data-bind="text: $data.content"></div>
```

javascript

```
var viewModel = {
    content: ko.observable('original')
};

var cpted = ko.computed(function(){
  alert(viewModel.content());
    return viewModel.content();
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

viewModel.content.notifySubscribers('new value');

alert(viewModel.content());
```

Comment: I am very curious why you want to "force the execution of subscribers" when the value hasn't changed. What are they doing if the value hasn't changed?

Comment: There is an example in this doc http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html, just search for notifySubscribers @Tyrsius

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`notifySubscribers` calls all the subscriptions that have registered for the given event. By default subscriptions are made to the `change` event, but the subscription system is built to support multiple events. Internally, Knockout also raises an event for `beforeChange`, which you can see in the source code [here](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/subscribable.js#L25).

The signature of the `subscribe` method (seen [here](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/subscribable.js#L38)) is

`subscribe: function (callback, callbackTarget, event)`

If you leave off the last parameter, `change` is used by default. But you can subscribe to the `beforeChange` event, or even **make your own events!** This is why `notifySubscribers` takes an event name.

You said you are trying to "force the execution of subscribers" when the value hasn't changed. Perhaps a custom event is better than the `change` event, since you are running it even when the value hasn't changed.

Comment: I don't get your answer, it seems irrelevant to me. @Tyrsius

Comment: @David I added some details, does that help? If not, please explain your confusion

Comment: I think I got the idea, my code snippet only contains the computed, so the passed valueToNotify is not used anywhere, but if I call viewModel.content.subscribe(aCallback), the valueToNotify is the first param for the aCallback. I think I was essentially confused by the difference between dependency and subscription, but that's a different question. @Tyrsius